# Working Directory for a Cron Job

Tags: php, mysql, cron, mamp, working-directory

I am testing an application in MAMP and would like to add a cron job, or as I am on a mac the job through is run  through `launchctl`.  My cron is a php file that runs a database query.  Naturally the php file and mysql db are in separate directories.  Where should I change my working directory to such that the cron will query the database?  FYI, I have a standard installation `/Applications/MAMP/...`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake above was that I was trying to point to the database's directory, when the php file had already handled that for me.  Running the program was as simple as running the following code:

```
php -q /path/to/my/doc.php
```

I found it was easiest to manage `launchtl` through a $5-$10 program called [lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/).  Highly recommended if you are considering managing multiple crons at a time. Otherwise, if you want to stick to the command line, [this](https://drupal.org/node/434416) is a good tutorial.